# ¿Cómo terminar un script de bash ante cualquier error?

Tags: bash

Si falla el comando `cd` en este script puede ser un desastre:

```
cd $HOME/el-directorio
rm -rf algo
```

Podría usar un if para comprobarlo pero cuando un script tiene docenas de comandos es costoso y propenso al error el tener que poner una comprobación cada vez.

¿Cómo hacer que el script de bash pare ante cualquier error?

Comment: Buena y útil aportación. Para mi sorpresa, descubrí que no es lo más recomendado: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Es interesante mirar los comentarios a la pregunta [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19622198/1983854) con alternativas, como `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: Muy interesante @fedorqui. Tengo que poner eso en mi respuesta cuando pueda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set -e
```

Esto hace que el script se detenga si cualquier comando devuelve un código de salida distinto de cero.
Hay algunas excepciones:

- Si el comando se usa con los operadores ||, && o !
- Si el comando está dentro de la condición de un while, until o if

Para devolver bash al comportamiento habitual:

```
set +e
```

El `set -e` también se puede activar con un parámetro al invocar bash:

```
bash -e el_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando **exit** se finaliza el shell script en cualquier momento. Por ejemplo incluye en tu código lo siguiente:

`exit 1`

1 indica un error general. 
Existen otros indicadores de error más específicos:

- 2: Falta palabra clave
- 127: Comando no encontrado
- 128: Argumento inválido en exit
- 130: Script terminado con control + C
- Y algunos otros: 126,128+n, 255*

Para tu ejemplo concreto, yo antes revisaría si el directorio existe:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORIO" ]; then cd "$DIRECTORIO"; echo "Borrando ALGO" rm -rf ALGO; else echo "El directorio $DIRECTORIO no existe"; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Lincoln. Pero me temo que no resonde a la pregunta. El objetivo es precisamente no tener que escribir un condicional con posible exit detrás de cada comando que pueda fallar (que son todos en general).

Comment: Cierto, revisando tu cuestión en detalle veo que descartas el IF. Buscas detener el script sobre un código ya escrito en cuanto encuentras un error, por lo que tampoco sirve llamar a una función que haga la verificación. Mal asunto. Re-escribe el código. ;-)